# Reading data into an uninitialized char pointer variable using fgets crashes at the second read

Tags: c, pointers, undefined-behavior, fgets

I am aware that we cannot read data into an uninitialized char pointer using fgets. There are quite a few questions relating to this very point here on stackoverflow. All the answers point to the fact that you can't load data into an uninitialized pointer variable.

The program shown in the first code snippet is able to populate the first uninitialized char pointer (*str2) using fgets but, crashes while trying to read data into the second uninitialized char pointer (*str3).

I can get it to work using the traditional methods like allocating memory to the pointer up-front (as shown in the second code snippet below) before populating. My question is why does it work for the first variable but not for the second?

**The Problem Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str1[100], *str2, *str3;
    // Prints fine

    printf("First String: ");
    fgets(str1, 20, stdin);
    printf("%s", str1);

    // Prints fine      
    printf("Second String: ");
    fgets(str2, 20, stdin);
    printf("%s", str2);

    // Program crashes on this input
    printf("Third String: ");
    fgets(str3, 20, stdin);
    printf("%s", str3);

    return 0;

}
```

**The Working Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str1[100], str2[20], str3[20];
    printf("First String: ");
    fgets(str1, 20, stdin);
    printf("%s", str1);

    printf("Second String: ");
    fgets(str2, 20, stdin);
    printf("%s", str2);

    printf("Third String: ");
    fgets(str3, 20, stdin);
    printf("%s", str3);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: you need to allocate memory for `str2` and `str3`.

Comment: Agreed. Why did it work for str2? That's the question I asked

Comment: *Undefined behavior* can sometimes seem to work.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - the *third* potential outcome :-)

Answer (score 5):

In your case

```
// Prints fine      
printf("Second String: ");
fgets(str2, 20, stdin);
printf("%s", str2);
```

contains the write to uninitialized pointer, which contains indeterminate value, which means, it invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Once your program has UB, nothing is guaranteed. One of the side-effects of having UB is to appear as "working (ab)normally", and a "crash" or segmentation fault is not guaranteed, either. It's just that, undefined.

*Moral of the story:* Do not try to reason with the output obtained from a program containing undefined behavior.

Comment: str2 is a pointer to a memory location which by definition should store chars. How many chars - I am not telling the program. If I explicitly do - for instance - str2 = 'Some String', things are fine. What is the difference between this manual update to the variable versus the one coming from fgets especially when I am explicitly providing to the fgets the size parameter (20, in my case)? This is what I am unable to intuit properly.

Comment: a statement like `str2 = "Some String";` does not write into the memory pointed to by `str2`, rather, it assigns the starting address of the string literal `"some string"` to `str2`. That's a different story.

Comment: okay - this is a great point - something which was conceptually vague in my head. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: But by the same token, the starting address of the string literal I am providing to str3 should get allocated to the str3 pointer variable? Isn't it?

Comment: You are not assigning any string literal to `str3`, @Stats_Lover.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I am not assigning to str2 either - it's fgets so the assignment is happening at run time via a command line input (for both str2, for which the program works and str3 where it crashes and which is what the question is about)

Comment: No, @Stats_Lover.  `fgets` does not assign to the pointer, period.  It does not assign the address of a string literal.  It does not assign any other pointer value.  Instead, it writes data to the location designated by the value the pointer already has.  That's a *completely* different thing, and for the effect to be defined, that value already held by the pointer must be a valid pointer to a sufficiently-large space.

Answer (score 1):

Just because you are using an uninitialized pointer is not a guarantee that the program will crash. Undefined behavior often times results in unpredictability. In your particular case, on your machine and with your compiler the pointer just happens to point to valid memory even if uninitialized, but this may change from compiler to compiler and from machine to machine.

Comment: `Undefined behavior often times results in unpredictability` - isn't it more like all the times?

Comment: Predictably unpredictable - or something.

Comment: ... and it may change from execution to exsecution. Or it may start crashing after the next reboot or after you logout/login again

Comment: @SouravGhosh "Undefined behaviour often times results in unpredictability" is a perfectly valid statement. Unpredictability is one of the potential outcomes of undefined behaviour (we don't know *why* what is happening is happening OR *nothing* may happen at all in case of undefined behaviour)